# I m not able to copy data from my main table to my temporary table

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

below is the code:

```
CREATE TABLE maintable (
  Name varchar(10),
  phone_number numeric(10)
);
INSERT INTO maintable
  VALUES ("Max", 9896995632);
SELECT
  *
FROM maintable;
create table #TempTable as
maintable;
```

Comment: You should change `"Max"` to `'Max'`

Comment: The syntax for SQL Server is: `SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM MainTable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Change From:**

```
create table #TempTable as maintable;
```

**To:**

```
select * into #TempTable from maintable
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Use Insert into in select statement.Now main table data move to temp table

CREATE TABLE maintable (Name varchar(10),phone_number numeric(10));
INSERT INTO maintable  VALUES ('Max', 9896995632);

SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM maintable

SELECT * FROM #TempTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Sql Server try this

```
SELECT * INTO #TempTable FROM MainTable
```

using Mysql try this

```
CREATE TABLE TempTable  LIKE maintable;
INSERT INTO TempTable SELECT * FROM maintable ;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also try this:

```
insert into #temptable(columnname)
select coloumnname from maintable
```

It will better help you to insert table values to the next time you perform insert operation.